# batch file renaming in vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I have a group of files that are named as such (word can be any word or numbers):

```
Word word-word word word Floor B2342 Word Word-word.pdf
Word word-word word Floor: B-2342 Word Word-word.pdf
Word word- Floor C43 Word Word.pdf
Word word word- Floor- E2AD342 Word Word.pdf
```

I want to rename everything in the folder to only have the group that follows Floor... You can count on Floor always being in the file name and what I want to keep following floor.

```
B2342.pdf
B-2342.pdf
C43.pdf
E2AD342.pdf
```

Comment: So what's the question?  You can't just expect someone to write the code for you.  Give it a try, then post here if you run into problems or have specific questions.

Answer (score 3):

Pass the path of the folder you want to process as the first argument to this script. You might have to tweak the regular expression for your input.

```
Set expr = New RegExp
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fpath = fs.GetFolder(WScript.Arguments(0))

expr.Pattern = "Floor\S*\s+([^\s.]*)"

For Each fspec In fpath.Files
    Set matches = expr.Execute(fspec.Name)
    If matches.Count = 0 Then
        WScript.StdErr.WriteLine "Invalid file name " & fspec.Name
    Else
        fspec.Move fspec.ParentFolder & "\" & matches(0).Submatches(0) & ".pdf"
    End If
Next
```